# Membership to double cosets in free groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, free-groups, gap

1. **Is there an elementary and efficient algorithm for testing the membership to a double coset of f.g. subgroups in a free group?**
2. **Has this membership problem been implemented in GAP/Magma?**

More precisely, I have a finitely generated free group $F$, two finitely generated subgroups $A,B$, given by their free generating sets, and an element $f\in F$. I would like to determine whether $f \in AB$.

I was hoping for something in the spirit of Stallings core graphs, but the standard reference (the paper of Kapovich and Myasnikov [*Kapovich, Ilya; Myasnikov, Alexei*, [**Stallings foldings and subgroups of free groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jabr.2001.9033), J. Algebra 248, No. 2, 608-668 (2002). [ZBL1001.20015](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1001.20015).]) does not seem to treat membership to double cosets.

Theoretically the required algorithm certainly exists. In fact, a much stronger property was proved by Grunschlag ( see Theorem 4.10 in [*Grunschlag, Zeph*, Computing angles in hyperbolic groups, Gilman, Robert H. (ed.), Groups, languages and geometry. 1998 AMS-IMS-SIAM joint summer research conference on geometric group theory and computer science, South Hadley, MA, USA, July 5-9, 1998. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society. Contemp. Math. 250, 59-88 (1999). [ZBL0953.20034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0953.20034).]

Comment: The answer is yes to 1 in cubic time at worse

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg: is it written anywhere?

Comment: It was proved by benois long before Grunschlag he is using her result

Comment: In several places.  It is a special case of the rational subset membership problem.  I’ll write the algorithm in an answer

Comment: It is a special case of the result of https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-17220-3_11

Comment: Thanks, I have indeed found a reference to Benois' 1968 paper in Grunschlag's article. He also mentions the work of Gilman in the same passage.

Comment: Yes, Gilman rediscovered the algorithm,  Actually the 68 paper is not really written in an algorithmic way but Benois redid it later the way I wrote it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a second answer that is just rephrasing @DerekHolt’s answer based on the comments. So upvote his answer first!  Let $X$ be a finite alphabet.  An inverse automaton is a finite directed graph labeled over the alphabet $X$ which is folded in the sense of Stallings, meaning you cannot find two edges entering or leaving a vertex with the same label.  Equivalently these are immersions over a bouquet of circles.  An inverse automaton has a unique initial state and a set of final states.  It recognizes a subset of the free group by looking at all reduced words labelling a path from the initial state to a final state, where inverse letters read edges backward.  The language accepted by an inverse automaton is a finite union of cosets of finitely generated subgroups.

The languages accepted by inverse automata are closed under intersection.  You simply build the product automaton whose vertices are pairs of vertices and there is an edge labeled by $x$ from $(p,q)$ to $(p’,q’)$ if and only if there are edges from $p$ to $p’$ and $q$ to $q’$ labeled by $x$.  This construction is the fiber product of the two inverse automata viewed as immersions over a bouquet of circles.   The initial state is the pair of initial states and the final states are those pairs $(p,q)$ where both $p$ and $q$ are final in their respective automata.  This is an inverse automata that will accept precisely those reduced words which both automata accept.  In particular, the intersection is empty iff the initial vertex of the product construction cannot reach any terminal vertex.

Now to recognize $Hw$ write a linear automaton reading the word $w$ (with inverse letters read backward) and attach at the initial point a generating set for $H$ as loops and apply Stallings foldings.  The initial vertex is the intial vertex of $w$ and the final vertex is the end point of $w$.  These may collapse after folding. This is essentially the Stallings core of $H$ with a thorn labeled $w$ sticking out of the base point and Stallings uses this automaton in his proof of Marshall Hall's Theorem.

We can do a similar thing for $gK$, but we put the generators of $K$ as loops at the end of the path labelled $g$, and then to test if $w\in HgK$ we just form the product automaton for $Hw$ and $gK$ and check if the final state is reachable from the initial state.

Note $w=hgk$ iff $h^{-1}w=gk$.  So $Hw$ and $gK$ intersect iff $w\in HgK$.

Comment: Yes, I got it backwards

Comment: My first answer is overkill because it solves a much more general problem and I didn’t bother to think if your problem was inherently easier.

Comment: Thank you, this is great!

Comment: you are welcome.  But I think it is what Derek was saying

Comment: I think that both of your answers are useful: this answer is good if you need to check whether just one element belongs to the double coset, so you build an automaton specifically for that element. Your other answer allows to build a single automaton, which works for all inputs!

Comment: Note that, topologically, this is precisely the *fibre product* that Stallings describes in his famous paper. So the algorithm is easily stated in terms of graphs: fold to construct core graphs for $H$ and $K$ (big enough to contain the elements of interest); construct the fibre product explicitly; now check whether or not the points corresponding to the elements you’re interested in are in the same component of the graph.

Comment: @HJWR,  I also mentioned the fiber product viewpoint in my comments on Derek's answer

Comment: Ah yes, I found it deep in the comment thread! I think it’s a shame that it isn’t mentioned prominently though, since the topological point of view in terms of graphs and fibre products is the primary modern way of thinking about subgroups of free groups. Perhaps I’ll add another answer to that effect...

Comment: @HJRW, I add a comment that the product of inverse automata is the fiber product of the corresponding immersions and emphasized inverse automata are immersions over bouquets.

Comment: @HJWR I also added Stallings users the coset version of the core in his proof of M Hall's Theorem

Answer (score 6):

Benois gave a Stallings type algorithm before Stallings to compute membership in any rational subset of a free group on a set $X$.  A rational subset $R$ is given by a finite automoaton over the alphabet $X\cup X^{-1}$.  An element $g\in FG(X)$ of the free group belongs to $R$ if some word which freely reduces to $g$ is accepted by the automaton.  Note that you are not allowed to read an edge in the backward direction and the automaton can be non-deterministic and have epsilon-transitions.

For a double coset $HgK$ you build an automaton where the generators of $H$ and their inverses read loops at the initial state, then there is a sequence of edges spelling out $g$ landing at the final state which has loops labeled by the generators of $K$ and their inverses.  If $g$ is the identity you should use an epsilon transition.

Here is the Benois algorithm.  We start off with an automaton and we add epsilon transitions until we guarantee that whenever a word is readable between two states, then so is its free reduction. First of all, we search for paths of length two labelled $xx^{-1}$ or $x^{-1}x$ and we add an epsilon transiiton from the beginning of the path to the end of the path (epsilon means empty word).  This is the analogue of Stallings folding  Inducitvely, we search for paths of the form $\epsilon\epsilon$ or $x\epsilon x^{-1}$ or $x^{-1}\epsilon x$ ($x$ a generator) and if there is no epsilon edge from the beginning to the end of this path of length 2 or 3, we add one.  Since we never changed the number of vertices, in a finite number of steps we will not be able to add any new epsilon edges. The resulting automaton is called saturated.

Notice that none of these new epsilon edges change the image of this rational set in the free group.  But once it is saturated, whenever we can read a word between two vertices, we can also read its reduced form.  Hence the set of reduced words accepted by the saturated automaton is exactly our rational subset of the free group.  There is a well known automaton which accepts precisely the reduced words and there is a well known direct product construction that builds an automaton which recognizes the intersection of two regular languages and so you can build an automaton which recognizes exactly the reduced words in your rational subset.

Details can be found in [Theorem 3.3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.1532.pdf#page21) I believe.  My memory is that this can be implemented in no worse than cubic time in the size of the automaton (which will be the natural size in the double coset case), but I haven’t thought about that in years.

**Added.** You can also solve this problem in virtually free groups.  Here is another algorithm for free groups that also works for virtually free groups.  Recall by Muller-Schupp that a group is virtually free if and only if its word problem is a context-free language.  Most reasonable ways of describing a virtually free group will give that context-free grammar.  Now if $R$ is a rational subset of a virtually free group (like a double coset of finitely generated subgroup), then $g\in R$ if and only if $1\in g^{-1}R$ and so it suffices to be able to solve the question given a finite automaton over the alphabet of the group, is the intersection of the word problem with the regular subset recognized by the automaton non-empty?  But the intersection of a context-free language and a regular language is always context-free and emptiness is decidable for context-free languages.

Comment: Thank you for such a useful answer! It seems to me that the main difference from Stallings foldings is that we add $\epsilon$-edges instead of folding. I wonder if Stallings' method can be made to work here as well? To decide if $g \in HK$, build the automaton for $HgK$, as you suggest, marking the start vertex and the end vertex by different colours. Apply Stallings foldings to the resulting graph. Then $g \in HK$ iff the start and end vertices have been identified after the foldings are done.

Comment: The problem is if you do HgK and g is in H or K you will fold things into the subgroup graph for <H,K>.  Folding only works really for things like subgroups where there is no left to right direction.

Comment: Also I added a slight correction in that you have to have loops for the inverse generators for H and K to get the subgroup instead of submonoid.

Comment: So, in your automaton you can only consider directed paths? For Stallings graphs, one can move against the direction of an edge, by reading the inverse of its label... Also, do you assume that $g \neq 1$, to ensure that the start and the accept vertices in the automaton for $HgK$ are distinct?

I've realised that the method I suggest above will generate the core graph for $\langle H,gKg^{-1}\rangle$, so the start and ennd vertices get identified iff $g \in \langle H,gKg^{-1}\rangle$.

Comment: That's right, you are only allowed to follow edges in the correct direction.  Otherwise you wouldn't be able to us this algorithm to check membership in submonoids and also if you could read the g edge backward you would get into trouble

Comment: I don't assume $g=1$ I use an epsilon transition so the endpoints are different.  I had edited it to make that clear.  Sorry, I have been using the construction for over 20 years so I forget that it might not be clear to others.

Comment: Sorry, the previous comment should say $g\neq 1$

Answer (score 6):

Concerning implementations in GAP and Magma, there is a GAP package for handling subgroups of free groups, but I don't know whether that has the built-in functionality to do what you want.

I know more about the facilities in Magma (I coded some of them myself). It can do membership testing in finitely generated subgroups of free groups, and it does this by building a finite state automaton to recognize membership of reduced words in the subgroup. (This is constructed using coset enumeration, which is algorithmically the same as Stallings Folding.) It can also construct an automaton recognizing the intersection of two subgroups.

The problem here reduces to computing the intersection of cosets of finitely generated subgroups. There is currently no function that computes the automaton recognizing membership of a coset, but I could easily write one. One could then immediately compute the required intersections (as an automaton), which would allow membership testing.

Comment: Thank you for the update on GAP and MAGMA! It is not worth writing a code for my question, I was just wondering whether all such algorithms concerning subgroups of free groups have already been implemented.

Comment: That is a good point, double cosets membership is equivalent to coset intersection emptiness which can be done essentially with Stallings graphs.

Comment: I was interested in the old days in membership in products $gH_1\cdots H_k$ with $H_1,\ldots, H_k$ finitely generated subgroups.  By the Ribes and Zalesskii theorem all closures of regular languages in a free group in the profinite topology are a finite union of sets of that form.  Here you can’t get away with just using subgroup graphs.

Comment: To spell it out, $w\in HgK$ iff $wH\cap gK$ is nonempty

Comment: So, you're suggesting to build automatons for the coset $Af$ and the subgroup $B$, then use the direct product construction, to construct an automaton accepting the intersection of $Af$ and $B$. This intersection is non-empty iff there is a directed path from the start vertex to the accept vertex... Still, you have to be careful with directed edges...

Comment: @AshotMinasyan, I’m not so sure.  I think that the intersection of the two cosets is empty iff the start and end are in different connected components even if you are allowed to go backward.  Intuitively you are checking if the orbit of wH in the coset graph under $K$ hits g.  So I think direction doesn’t matter but to be safe you formally should have inverses edges and keep track of direction.  But it may not be necessary.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg, I don't see why this method is much easier that the method suggested in your answer. Don't you still need to saturate the automaton, and then construct the automaton for the intersection?

Comment: @AshotMinasyan, I guess it is not easier if you do what I said formally to do.  But if you can get away with allowing yourself to travel in either direction along the edges, then it is easier.

Comment: @AshotMinasyan, my guess is you can just view the Stallings graph for H with a thorn reading from w to the base point (folded in) and the Stallings graph for K with a thorn reading g going into the base point (folded in), these are graph immersions over the bouquet.  Take the fiber product immersion and can the pair start(g),start(w) reach the pair base point, base point where you can move along edges in either direction and don’t formally include inverse edges.

Comment: Yes, a reduced word $z$ would read in that fiber product from (start,start) to (end,end) iff it belongs to $wH\cap gK$ and so there is no need to throw in direction or anything.  This is much easier than general rational subsets.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I think you mean $w \in HgK$ if and only if $Hw \cap gK$ is nonempty. It makes a slight difference from my viewpoint as someone who does implementations, because the automaton for membership of $gK$ is a lot easier to construct from that of $K$ than for $Hw$. I would probably use $Hw = (w^{-1}H)^{-1}$ to do that, but then you need to read the input word backwards. Personally I think the approach I describe is a lot easier, but that's because I could complete the implementation in at most a few hours.

Comment: Incidentally, all of this generalizes to quasiconvex subgroups of hyperbolic groups, although for that there would be more work to do to implement it for coset membership rather than subgroup membership.

Comment: Hw is w(w^{-1}Hw) if it makes implementation easier.  That's what my version of your argument does.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Yes thanks, that reduces the amount of work I would need to do, because I can use the existing functionality to construct the automaton for $w^{-1}Hw$. I might actually do this next week, just in case anyone really want to solve such a problem!

Comment: Dear @DerekHolt, many thanks for your answer. I could only accept one answer, and Benjamin Steinberg's second answer was precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: @AshotMinasyan Yes that's fine - he has described the details of what is going on. If you have any actual instances of this problem that you think would e interesting then please let me know, because I might try and implement it in Magma - I don't expect it to take long, because nearly all of the machinery is there already.

Comment: @AshotMinasyan I implemented Benois' algorithm in GAP a while ago, if you're interested (though it's far from optimised).

Comment: Thanks for offering your help with the software! For my concrete example, I managed to apply Benjamin Steinberg’s solution by hand: the resulting automaton only had 12 states.

Comment: Great! Yes, usually these are not too difficult when the states are few. In the reasonable-time cases I used it for, the resulting automata would have maybe $200$ states and $20000$ transitions, or so, for reference.